# Create a loop of falling objects

Tags: animation, physics, animation-nodes, rigid-body-simulation, loop

I'm trying to create a scene with marbles falling down on a plane, I want to loop this like a long gif to where it seams like infinite marbles falling.  The problem I am having in getting it to loop well.  if I do a rigid body simulation, the marbles fall then roll off the plane.  The problem is having the animation loop.  I do not want it to be packets of marbles falling then off screen and only the plane showing.  I want it to look continuous falling marbles with no brakes.  I cant think of how to loop this. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you could try is baking the rigid body animation, duplicating it, then offsetting the animation to look like the duplicated is starting just as the original is ending

Comment: please show us what you tried so far. Best would be: you provide your .blend file. Then we can help you perfectly with your loop!

Comment: Baking the rigid body sim worked for me. Thanks.